# Disable JavaScript for InternetExplorer.Application?

Tags: .net, powershell, comobject

How can JavaScript be disabled programmatically for a `InternetExplorer.Application` ComObject before retrieving the contents of a web document?

```
$comIE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$comIE.Visible   = $True;
$comIE.Navigate("https://www.google.com")

Do { Sleep 1 } Until (-not $comIE.Busy)   

$ieDoc = $comIE.Document;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it via the registry key. See the documentation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569). I would avoid changing security settings in this manner and do it via group policy instead.

Comment: This would affect all IE sessions. I only want to disable JS for the specific session used by the code. Thank you though!

Comment: I dont think your code should run for very long. Disable it before calling your script and reenable it at the end.